# Docker Compose Build Failure with .NET 6 and React Project: Unexpected End of Statement Error

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm working on a project using .NET 6 integrated with React and attempting to containerize it using Docker. When running docker-compose build. The error seems to point to a syntax issue, but I cannot pinpoint the exact cause. It's unclear whether Docker is misinterpreting a part of my Dockerfile or if there's an error in my docker-compose configuration. I encounter the following error:

```
server: error reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed
failed to solve: failed to process ".\"]": unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote
```

[https://ibb.co/5K3R7cB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWxCz.png)

```
# Backend
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LIA_TEST/LIA_TEST.csproj", "LIA_TEST/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LIA_TEST/LIA_TEST.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/LIA_TEST"
RUN dotnet build "LIA_TEST.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "LIA_TEST.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LIA_TEST.dll"]
```

```
# Frontend
FROM node:alpine as web-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY LIA_TEST/ClientApp/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY LIA_TEST/ClientApp/. .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine as web
COPY --from=web-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikHNO.png)
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "7175:80"

  web:
    build:
      context: ./ClientApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "44482:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LIA_TEST.dll"]` into `ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "LIA_TEST.dll" ]` and `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` into `CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried adjusting the spacing in the ENTRYPOINT and CMD as recommended, but unfortunately, the issue persists. Could there be any other potential causes or steps I can explore to resolve this?